# Executing Python Script from C#

Tags: c#, python

I am trying to execute the python script from C# in the following way:

```
int ExitCode;
ProcessStartInfo ProcessInfo;
Process Process;

ProcessInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
ProcessInfo.FileName = "C:\Python27\python.exe";
ProcessInfo.Arguments = "C:\generate.py book1.pdf";
ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process = Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
Process.WaitForExit();
ExitCode = Process.ExitCode;
Process.Close();
```

When I execute this on the server, I get the ExitCode as 1. But the same code is working fine locally.

Also when I run this command from the cmd prompt, the python script executes without any issues.

This python script is actually being used to convert the PDF pages to SWF files, extract the text from pages and create thumbnail of the pdg pages using various open sources.

Can anyone please help me understand what could be the issue with above C# code or do I need to set any permissions on the server?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried running this command from the command line on your *server*?

Comment: Yes, I am able to run this command from the command line on server. I am able to get the desired output from the command.

Comment: Does your C# application run under the same user account or is it a service?

Comment: It's the web application in which I am trying to execute this command from C#.

Comment: Does the python script write the output to a file? If yes, then check if the user under which the web application runs has the permission to write files to the output location.

Comment: Yes, the python script writes the output to a file. The output location has full permissions and also for testing purpose, I have given the full permissions to Everyone User for all the system drives. But still the Process ExitCode is returned as 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27927/discussion-between-amar-and-dominic-kexel)

Comment: @Amar, make sure that "C:\generate.py book1.pdf" isn't passed as a single argument (although my python (3 on Windows 7 x64) returns `2` exit code in such cases).

Comment: @Amar have you solved your problem?

Comment: Have you solved the problem? I have a very similar problem as yours.

Answer (score 2):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) error code 2 stands for `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, so you should have some problem with the path/file permissions.

First of all you can just read the stdout and stderr from the python process and see if you get some information from there:

```
    ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    // (...)
    Process.WaitForExit();
    string stderr = Process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
    string stdout = Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine("STDERR: " + stderr);
    Console.WriteLine("STDOUT: " + stdout);
```

Probably WriteLine is not the best way to present the information, so adapt it to better suit your needs (log that information, write it on a temp file, etc).

Also I barely know how to program in C#, but when I tried to write a program similar to yours it gave me an error because paths were not escaped. So you can also try to replace \ with \\:

```
ProcessInfo.FileName = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
ProcessInfo.Arguments = "C:\\generate.py book1.pdf";
```

Good luck.

#### Edit

I just noticed I confused your error code(1) with others on the comments(2),but those tips may still help you.